# MYSQL - IN selector but getting ALL

Tags: mysql

I search my sql table using in:

```
videos.category in ($categoriesSelected)
```

I pass through the categories based on what a user selects. Sometimes when a user selects no categories I want all videos to be displayed, Ive tried changing the $categoriesSelected var to * but no luck.

Will I have to do a seperate query taking out 'in' for when I want to display all, or is there a way to change $categoriesSelected to display all? Note, I do not want to just prefil it with the names of all my categories as this constantly changes via a CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query is built dynamically and you happen to not escape the value of `$categoriesSelected`
you could try `videos.category IN (videos.category)`.

Note: this is a dummy hack and you better rewrite the whole section of code that builds the query.

Answer (score 0):

You must do a check to see if something is in $categoriesSelected - if yes then do your actual query, else do the query without the `IN` clause

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in `'SELECT category FROM categories'` for your $categoriesSelected.

Change category to be the field name that stores your category name.